EF Core 8 - Cannot access a disposed context instance
I am using dependency injection to initiate my DbContext in my Blazor web app (server-side).
Here's the error I get:

Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'BKRContext'.

And here is my code:
using BKR.DB;
using BKR.Web.Components;
using BKR.WEB.Services;
using BKR.WEB.Services.Contracts;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<BKRContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("BKRConnection"),
    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
    {
        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
    });
});


builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();


app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>().DisableAntiforgery().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();

using BKR.Model;
using BKR.WEB.Services.Contracts;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using BKR.DB;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace BKR.WEB.Services
{
    public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
    {
        private readonly BKRContext dbcontext;

        public CustomerService(BKRContext bkrdbcontext)
        {
            this.dbcontext = bkrdbcontext;    
        }

        public async ValueTask<BKR.Model.Customer> CreateCustomer(BKR.Model.Customer dto)
        {
            BKR.Model.Customer bolObj = new BKR.Model.Customer()
            
            try
            {
                var result = await this.dbcontext.Customers.AddAsync(bolObj);
                await this.dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();// <<-- Error here
                return result.Entity;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}

using BKR.Model;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
namespace BKR.DB;
public class BKRContext : DbContext
{
    //public BKRContext()
    //{
    //}

    public BKRContext(DbContextOptions<BKRContext> dbContextOptions)
        : base(dbContextOptions)
    {
        //Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    //protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    //{
    //    IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
    //    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("BKRConnection"));
    //}
}

Any ideas why this error happens?
Thanks in advance

Blazor web app (server-side) you should use a DbContextFactory instead.

Is there any specific reason for using connection pooling in BKRContext. In Blazor Server apps, it’s often best to use AddDbContext instead of AddDbContextPool to avoid issues with pooled contexts. Since you're using Dependency Injection (DI) to manage the lifecycle of your DbContext,  so  inadvertently disposing of the context can cuase the exception you are getting.

Also is this one ValueTask<BKR.Model.Customer> typos or what? It should be Task<BKR.Model.Customer>.

A bit offtopic but worth mentioning. According to documentation you should not use AddAsync method. Look at this paragraph: This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used.


I am using dependency injection to initiate my DbContext in my Blazor
web app (server-side).
Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this
error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from
dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context
instance elsewhere in your application.

Based on your scenario and description, uses of AddDbContextPool causing the exception. Because, in Blazor Server apps, components have longer lifetimes compared to regular HTTP requests. Pooled contexts can lead to complications if a component holds onto a context instance longer than expected, causing it to be reused in an inappropriate scope.
In this scenario,the recommended approach to create a new DbContext with dependencies is to use a factory.
Considering all those thing, in ordrer to overcome the exception, you could modify you dbContext configuration in program.cs file as following:
If you want to use DbContextFatory then you could do as following:
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<BKRContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("BKRConnection"),
    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
    {
        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
    });
});

If you want without Factory then:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<BKRContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("BKRConnection"),
    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
    {
        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
    });
});

Note: Also, if you are manually disposing of the DbContext anywhere be aware of that, usually we don't need to manually handle that as The DI container will handle this for us. Please refer to this official document for additional details.

Blazor applications do not create a scope for each request, so you cannot directly inject ICustomerService into a controller and use it alongside DbContext. To make minimal changes, instead of injecting ICustomerService, inject IServiceScopeFactory.
In your controller:
public class SomeController
{
    readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public SomeController(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public async Task<BKR.Model.Customer> SomeMethod(BKR.Model.Customer dto)
    {
        using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();

        var customerService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICustomerService>();
        return await customerService.CreateCustomer(dto);
    }
}

Manually creating a scope will instantiate scoped instances and release created resources upon disposal.
